# deploying a website on remote server using MSBuild

Tags: deployment, msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

I have created the deployment package for a project and now I need to deploy it on a remote server. All this has to be done using MSBuild. I used MSBuild to create the package and deploy it on local machine. Being new to .net as well as MSBuild,I am not sure how to do it.Can it be done using the MSBuildExtensionsPack

Answer (score 0):

I guess the basic steps are:

1. Stop IIS on remote server.
2. Move new files.
3. Start IIS on remote server.
4. (Optional) some kind of smoke screen test.

Stop and Start IIS

[Stop IIS 7 Application Pool from build script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395498/stop-iis-7-application-pool-from-build-script)

```
 <AppPoolController ApplicationPoolName="AnAppPool" Action="Restart" ServerName="MyServer"/>
```

Ftp the new code?

[MSBuild Community Tasks Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762839/msbuild-community-tasks-documentation)

(or copy over the network with msbuild copy task)